# Why am I missing a system file relating to Ruby on OSX 10.10.5?

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew

I'm trying to install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) on my Mac running OSX 10.10.5 with the following script…

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

…but am getting the following error in the terminal:

```
/usr/local/Library/ENV/scm/git: line 10: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Library/ENV/scm/git: line 10: exec: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: cannot execute: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Library/ENV/scm/git: line 10: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Library/ENV/scm/git: line 10: exec: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: cannot execute: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Library/brew.sh: line 250: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
/usr/local/Library/brew.sh: line 250: exec: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby: cannot execute: No such file or directory
Failed during: /usr/local/bin/brew tap homebrew/core
```

This error also appears after running any `brew` command.

I can run Ruby 2.0.0p481, and have Xcode Version 7.2.1 (7C1002) installed, which is the latest version available to me. I'm also able to uninstall Homebrew using this script with no errors:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

Originally, I thought it was a permissions issue, so have tried…

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local`

…with no success.

I then searched for the path mentioned in the error. *Current* shows as an alias, and when I attempt to open it, I get the following error:

```
The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “Current” can’t be found.
```

I can navigate to the `/usr/bin/Ruby` path through the Finder, but am unsure whether this relates to the path in the error.

I don't believe I've touched the Ruby installation, so I'm unsure why there's an error.

The Terminal now shows the following upon opening a Terminal window:

```
-bash: rbenv: command not found
-bash: rbenv: command not found
-bash: rbenv: command not found
```

My ultimate goal is to compile and install [Tiled Map Editor](http://www.mapeditor.org) on my Mac running OSX 10.10.5. I had previously installed Homebrew, so [followed the instructions](https://github.com/bjorn/tiled/blob/master/README.md) for compiling Tiled Map Editor, which is when I came across the problem.

Comment: Well, does `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby` exist?

Comment: @jtbandes I touched on that towards the end. It doesn't appear so, but I don't know why.

Comment: You could try re-installing the 10.10.5 update.

Comment: @jtbandes It's an option, but definitely a last resort. Homebrew has worked on this version before, anyway.

Comment: It seems concerning that you would be missing a system library.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found out why I'm missing a system file, but rather than reinstall the whole OS, I followed the instructions found in [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/860819/reinstall-ruby-framework-on-os-x-yosemite) to reinstall Essentials from the Yosemite installer, which includes Ruby.

Homebrew now installs as expected.